# Transferring TRC-20 Token using TronLink

Tags: javascript, cryptocurrency, tron, tronlink

please am trying to integrate sending any trc20 token using tronlink by clicking a button on my website. I was able to send TRX using the JavaScript code below but I want to be able to send trc-20  like USDT, any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="numb" id="numb">
            <button onclick="sendtron()">Can you get tronweb from tronlink?</button>
      </div>
    <script>
        function sendtron(){
        var obj = setInterval(async ()=>{
            if (window.tronWeb && window.tronWeb.defaultAddress.base58) {
                clearInterval(obj)
                var tronweb = window.tronWeb
                var amount = document.querySelector('#numb').value;
                var tokens = amount * 1000000
                var tx = await tronweb.trx.sendTransaction("TWs2Z7dLMcPnXi9pnWqCUPzAnqUv6T54dy", tokens)
                var signedTx = await tronweb.trx.sign(tx)
                var broastTx = await tronweb.trx.sendRawTransaction(signedTx)
                console.log(broastTx);
                
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

TRC20 are actually smart contracts. [tronscan USDT link](https://tronscan.org/#/token20/TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t) To transfer TRC20 from your address to another address, you will be calling TRC20's transfer function, below is a snippet of Tron USDT's code.

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

    // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }
```

[TronWeb TRC20 Contract Interaction](https://developers.tron.network/docs/trc20-contract-interaction) documentation. You can use [tronWeb's triggerSmartContract function](https://developers.tron.network/reference#triggersmartcontract) to create a raw transaction, sign and broadcast.

1. create raw transaction

```
var senderAddress = tronweb.defaultAddress.base58;
var receiverAddress = "TV3nb5HYFe2xBEmyb3ETe93UGkjAhWyzrs"; 
var amount = 100;
var parameter = [{type:'address',value:receiverAddress},{type:'uint256',value:amount}]
var options = {
  feeLimit:100000000                    
}

const transactionObject = await tronWeb.transactionBuilder.triggerSmartContract(
    tronweb.address.toHex(contractAddress), 
    "transfer(address,uint256)", 
    options, 
    parameter,
    tronweb.address.toHex(senderAddress)
);
```

Note: address are all in base58 format, we need to convert it to hex format using `tronweb.address.toHex(address)` at `transactionObject`. The `parameter` variable is where we set the receiver address and amount.

2. Sign

```
var signedTransaction = await tronWeb.trx.sign(transactionObject.transaction);
```

3. Broadcast

```
var broadcastTransaction = await tronWeb.trx.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction);
console.log(broadcastTransaction);
```